# Non negative eigenvalues of a 10 by 10 matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I am trying the following question from a competitive exam :
Let A be 10 by 10 matrix with complex entries such that all its eigenvalues are non negative real numbers and at least one eigenvalue is positive. I need to find the statement which is always false from :

A. $\exists$ a matrix B such that AB-BA=B

B. $\exists$ a matrix B such that AB-BA=A

C. $\exists$ a matrix B such that AB+BA=A

D. $\exists$ a matrix B such that AB+BA=B

I have no idea where to start from. I don't even know how the given data will be needed to find the false statement. Any help is appreciated. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** What can you say about the traces of the given matrices? (Alternatively, for three of the choices, one can find a suitable matrix $B$ for which the equation holds for all $A$.)

Comment: I know that trace of AB and BA is the same. So trace of all left hand side of option B is 0. Which would mean, trace of A is 0. How do I proceed to find a contradiction to something given?

Comment: How is the trace of a matrix $A$ related to its eigenvalues?

Comment: Oh yes! trace is equal to sum of eigenvalues. And that is not possible since all eigenvalues are non negative and one is positive. Thanks for the hints. :)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found them useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate answers A and D by noting that the zero matrix B always satisfies that identity.

Comment: And $C$ by noting that $B = \frac{1}{2} I$ always satisfies the identity.

Comment: Funny that we have never used the special properties of A. Using those, we can actually prove that statement B is always false as follows. Consider the matrices A and B as linear transformations of a 10-dimensional complex vector space, then the statement is equivalent to the existence of a certain linear transformation. Choose a new basis such that A is diagonal and its upper left entry is a positive real number a. Then the upper left entries of AB and BA are both equal to ab, where b is the upper left entry of b. But that would mean that the upper left entry of AB-BA=A is ab-ab=0=a.

Comment: Wow. I've never seen this kind of reasoning. Very impressive to me. Thanks Justpassingby. :)

Comment: @Justpassingby Not all matrices are diagonalizable.

Comment: Good point; I saw "real eigenvalues" and I immediately assumed (incorrectly) "self-adjoint". Could we save the argument by making A triangular with the positive real value in the upper left corner?